# Removable storage shortcut and a panel shortcuts

Tags: gnome, edubuntu

I have edubuntu 14.04.01 LTS with gnome.

[image]

I can't find out how to make 2 things that were previously possible/made on older edubuntu.

1. I want to have a shortcut on the desktop when I insert a removable storage
2. How to make shortcuts to apps like shown below (firefox, mail, help)

[image]

Comment: My question was answered on another forum.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Gnome tweak tool > Desktop** check the box on **Mounted Volumes**
2. <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+ right click on the top panel **Add to panel > application launcher**